# Search workbook for key phrases and copy column into new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-interop

I need to search a workbook for a few key phrases (always in the header row) and when the phrase is found copy the entire column to a new workbook, then carry on to find the next phrase.  When I recorded my macro this is what it gave me, but the key phrase may not always be in Column B so this could err quickly!  The scope of my project is to find these keywords, select the column until the last row with data, and copy into a separate workbook.  I will be merging 6 - 7 workbooks.

```
Cells.Select
Selection.Find(What:="Emp Name", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
    , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Copy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you don't say why you need it in C# but the VBA way to select the "current" column is:

```
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select
```

This will select whatever column contains the keyword.

The VBA to create a new workbook and paste in the column is just

```
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Sorry, I am needing to find the key word, highlight the column, and copy into a new workbook.

Comment: Well you said column in your question - do you need to amend your question appropriately?

Comment: No, it should be column...just a mishap on my part.